# Padua-type pointset for functions singular on line $x=y$

Tags: algorithms, interpolation, projection, chebyshev

The Padua points $\mathrm{Pad}_{n} \subset [-1,1]^{2}$ are a unisolvent pointset with optimal growth of Lebesgue constant, described in detail [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Stefano_De_Marchi/publication/220493368_Algorithm_886_Padua2D---Lagrange_Interpolation_at_Padua_Points_on_Bivariate_Domains/links/0912f50c24818e3388000000/Algorithm-886-Padua2D---Lagrange-Interpolation-at-Padua-Points-on-Bivariate-Domains.pdf). With some work they can be used to generate a multivariate Chebyshev series representation of the function they attempt to interpolate.

I would like to use the Padua points to generate a multivariate Chebyshev series of a function singular along the line $x=y$, but this is impossible because two of the Padua points are consecutive vertices of the square.

Is there a way to generate a multivariate Chebyshev polynomial interpolant of a function $f\colon [-1,1]^2\to \mathbb{R}$ which is singular on the line $x=y$, perhaps using a modification of the Padua points?

*Update*: The goal is to write a piece of code which projects as many 2D functions defined on rectangular regions as possible onto Chebyshev polynomials and allow for interpolation and recovery of the coefficients for perhaps other uses. This is similar to the goals of chebfun in 2D.

Comment: Is not a bit odd trying to interpolate a function with a discontinuity?

Comment: @nicoguaro: Gaussian quadrature of integrands with singular endpoints is the same thing-interpolating with a polynomial. Delta sequence approximations to Green's functions act in a similar way. It is delicate, and requires adaptivity, but it can be done. (Whether, in my case, it will actually work, is another question.)

Comment: Gaussian quadrature for functions with singularities is commonly done using orthogonal polynomials with respect to some weight function.

Comment: That works better, but it cannot be totally black boxed.

Comment: Gaussian quadrature of functions with singular endpoints still works, depending on the strength of the singularity.

Comment: Let me clarify: The goal is to construct a routine which constructs a Chebyshev series for as many functions as possible, and in 2d, functions singular on $x=y$ are common and relevant.

Comment: You should add those details to your question. Although, I am bit confused now do you want a Chebyshev interpolation or a Chebyshev series?

Comment: The series is required for the interpolation, so I was hoping that I could get both out of the same code.